# Combine a specific row from many data frames into one data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 20 data frames (dat.table1 to dat.table20) that look like this:

```
> dat.table1

           Mean         SD          LB         UB
1  -3.251915678 0.09831336 -3.44979982 -3.0579865
2   0.529393596 0.09403571  0.34492156  0.7138352
3   0.437666296 0.09555116  0.25218768  0.6230282
4   0.386773612 0.09338021  0.20630132  0.5708987
5   0.259218892 0.10023005  0.06538325  0.4610775
6  -0.048387041 0.07875680 -0.20517662  0.1020621
7   0.086933460 0.08688864 -0.08462830  0.2565562
8   0.206235709 0.08200178  0.04710170  0.3658142
9   0.343474976 0.08204759  0.18539931  0.5062159
10 -0.354694572 0.08556581 -0.52609169 -0.1916891
11 -0.270542304 0.07349095 -0.41319234 -0.1291315
12  0.124547080 0.08323933 -0.04331230  0.2836064
13  0.005354652 0.10487004 -0.20677503  0.2061523
14  0.296131787 0.08235691  0.13605602  0.4593168
15  0.246056104 0.07536908  0.09803849  0.3959664
16  0.271052276 0.08347047  0.10437983  0.4354910
17 -0.005474416 0.09352408 -0.19415321  0.1736560

> dat.table2
          Mean         SD          LB         UB
1  -3.32373198 0.10477638 -3.53563786 -3.1241599
2   0.58316739 0.09466424  0.39814125  0.7690037
3   0.47869295 0.09768017  0.28395734  0.6701996
4   0.44479756 0.09489120  0.26172536  0.6336547
5   0.30072454 0.09964341  0.10674064  0.4980277
6  -0.05397720 0.07987092 -0.20952979  0.1038290
7   0.06624190 0.08466350 -0.10406855  0.2297836
8   0.18411601 0.07997405  0.02953943  0.3433614
9   0.35256600 0.07871029  0.20079165  0.5111548
10 -0.39566218 0.08567173 -0.56842809 -0.2281193
11 -0.29250153 0.07652253 -0.44428227 -0.1435696
12  0.07428006 0.08742497 -0.09829608  0.2419713
13 -0.03926006 0.11335154 -0.26894891  0.1716172
14  0.30625276 0.08212213  0.14760732  0.4674057
15  0.26511644 0.07824379  0.11330060  0.4216398
16  0.25476552 0.08699879  0.08646282  0.4240095
17 -0.05081449 0.10151042 -0.25162773  0.1451824
```

My question is how do I pick specific row (say row 1) from all the data frames and combine them by rows in a new data frame?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to read the datasets in a `list` rather than creating/reading `20` datasets in the global enviroment and then do these kind of operations.  Having already created the `datasets`, you could do:

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern='^dat.table\\d+'))
res <- do.call(`rbind`,lapply(lst,function(x) x[1,]))

row.names(res) <- NULL
```

For the `two` datasets, you would get

```
res
#      Mean         SD        LB        UB
#1 -3.251916 0.09831336 -3.449800 -3.057987
#2 -3.323732 0.10477638 -3.535638 -3.124160
```

Another option would be to use `slice` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d1 <- unnest(lst, grp)
group_by(d1, grp) %>%
                  slice(1)
#       grp      Mean         SD        LB        UB
#1 dat.table1 -3.251916 0.09831336 -3.449800 -3.057987
#2 dat.table2 -3.323732 0.10477638 -3.535638 -3.124160
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(Map(cbind, grp=seq_along(lst), lst))[, head(.SD,1), by=grp]
#   grp      Mean         SD        LB        UB
#1:   1 -3.251916 0.09831336 -3.449800 -3.057987
#2:   2 -3.323732 0.10477638 -3.535638 -3.124160
```

#### Update

Regaring the error message, I would suspect the `column names` in any of the `lst` elements to be different. For example if I change

```
 colnames(lst[[1]])[1] <- "Mean1"
 do.call(`rbind`,lapply(lst,function(x) x[1,]))
 #Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
 #names do not match previous names
```

One option would be to change the column names to be the same if the columns are ordered similarly for each dataset

```
  nm1 <- sapply(lst, function(x) colnames(x))[,2] #Because I changed the 1st element
  #column name
  lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) {colnames(x) <- nm1; x} )
  res <- do.call(`rbind`,lapply(lst1,function(x) x[1,]))
  row.names(res) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.The `res` function return error:
    `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
    names do not match previous names`

Comment: Good catch with the wrong names.Apparently one of the data frames had "Estimate" instead of "Mean". But now when I run `res` I get an error:
`Error in x[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: @FadzliFuzi  It could be that your `data.frames` have different number of dimensions as the error shows. Check `sapply(lst1, dim)` and see if the numbers are different.

Comment: One of the dataset has `dim` NULL. I've coerced it to a data frame.Now `res` runs perfectly. Thanks for all your effort, I learned a lot today. People like you makes stackoverflow a great reference! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid having 20 similarly named data frames from the start... you could do something like this:

```
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv")
read_file  <- function(x) {df <- read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE); df$file = x; df}
file_list  <- lapply(files, read_file)

combined   <- do.call(rbind, file_list)
```

And that looks like this...

```
> head(combined)
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb      file
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 file1.csv
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 file1.csv
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 file1.csv
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 file1.csv
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 file1.csv
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 file1.csv
> tail(combined)
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb      file
91 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.7  0  1    5    2 file20.csv
92 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2 file20.csv
93 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.5  0  1    5    4 file20.csv
94 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.5  0  1    5    6 file20.csv
95 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.6  0  1    5    8 file20.csv
96 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.6  1  1    4    2 file20.csv
```

`list.files` searches your working directly (by default) for files ending in .csv.

`read_file` function will read in a file given its path, and add a column to say which file it came from.

`lapply` will then use `read_file` function on each file in `file_names`

`do.call` will combine the list of the data frames returned above into a single data frame.